# Writing specifique DataType

Tags: node.js, opc-ua

I try to write some Variant type on node-opcua.
I'm connected to WagoPLC (750-8202), but i can't figure out how to write on this specific datatype (writing on a boolean is OK).

Here is my node when I read it :

```
Variant{
   "dataType":22,
   "arrayType":0,
   "value":"Telerupteur"{
      "nomTechnique":"Lumiere_Bureau",
      "nom":"Bureau",
      "manual_switch":false,
      "manual_ON":false,
      "manual_OFF":false,
      "export_state":true
   },
   "dimensions":null
}
```

And here is my try to write it :
Hi !

I try to write some Variant type on node-opcua.
I'm connected to WagoPLC (750-8202), but i can't figure out how to write on this specific datatype (writing on a boolean is OK).

Here is my node when I read it :
Variant{
"dataType":22,
"arrayType":0,
"value":"Telerupteur"{
"nomTechnique":"Lumiere_Bureau",
"nom":"Bureau",
"manual_switch":false,
"manual_ON":false,
"manual_OFF":false,
"export_state":true
},
"dimensions":null
}

And here is my try to write it :

```
// Write the data
const statusCode = await this.session.write({
   "nodeId":"ns=4;s=|var|WAGO 780-8202.Maison_V3.Telerupteurs.Bureau",
   "attributeId":"AttributeIds.Value",
   "value":{
      "sourceTimestamp":"new Date()",
      "value":{
         "dataType":"DataType.ExtensionObject",
         "value":{
            "manual_switch":true
         }
      }
   }
});
```

But got this error :
`Error: A variant with DataType.ExtensionObject must have a ExtensionObject value.`

I didnt find how to write it correctly..
Can anyone help me to do it correctly ?

Answer (score 1):

Work now.
In case of research for others:

```
const opcua = require("node-opcua");

async function main() {
    const endpointUrl = "opc.tcp://opcua.umati.app:4843";
    const client = opcua.OPCUAClient.create({endpointMustExist: false});
    client.on("backoff", () => console.log("backoff"));
    await client.connect(endpointUrl);
    const session = await client.createSession({});
    const nodeId = "ns=32;i=6031" // node to write
    const dataType = opcua.coerceNodeId("ns=31;i=3003") // opcua structure / extensionobject
    const data = {
        name: "test",
        id: 23,
        parentStateId: 5,
        description: "asdf1234"
    }
    const exobj = await session.constructExtensionObject(dataType, data)

    // read 1
    console.log(await session.read({
        nodeId: nodeId,
        attributeId: opcua.AttributeIds.Value
    }))
    // Write the ExObj
    await session.write({
        nodeId: nodeId,
        attributeId: opcua.AttributeIds.Value,
        value: new opcua.DataValue({
            value: new opcua.Variant({
                value: exobj,
                dataType: opcua.DataType.ExtensionObject
            })
        })
    })
    // read 2
    console.log(await session.read({
        nodeId: nodeId,
        attributeId: opcua.AttributeIds.Value
    }))    
}

(async () => {
    await main()
})()
```